# Google maps change language dynamically (asynchronous loading)

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there any way to load language in the map options field?
Something like this:

```js
var mapOptions = {
  center : new google.maps.LatLng(43.97918, 53.716647),
  zoom : 10,
  mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  language : 'fr'
};
```

Comment: The JS here seems invalid, are you sure `fr` is not a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it!

Using google script https://www.google.com/jsapi

`google.load('maps', '3.x', {
            'other_params' :
            'sensor=true&libraries=geometry&language=' + langCode,
            'callback' : mapsLoadeds
    });`

mapsLoaded executes the common code for creating maps.

Comment: I tried to do the same, but console says that google.load is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `language` parameter in the url of google maps :

```html
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&language=ja">
</script>
```